# Python get only starting number sequences from the string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get starting number sequences from the string.

sample strings.

```
1.2 Sky is blue.
1.2.1 Data is read 2 times.
3 Call the cops.
5.0.0.1 This is not bad.
this is cool
```

expect op

```
1.2 Sky is blue.                ==> 1.2
1.2.1 Data is read 2 times.     ==> 1.2.1
3 Call the cops.                ==> 3
5.0.0.1 This is not bad.        ==> 5.0.0.1
this is cool                    ==> (skip this)
```

I have tried to split the string using space but it is not a good idea I think.

UPDATE :

Some string don't start with a number.

Comment: Why do you think splitting is not a good idea? (Asking because it _is_.)

Comment: Why do you think it is not a good idea? Do you have strings that do not start with numbers?

Comment: I thought regex will be better

Comment: yes some string are not start with number

Comment: So, `r"^(\d(\.\d)*) (.+)"`

Comment: If some strings do not start with a number, then you should mention it in the question and give proper examples. If a string does not start with a number, can it have numbers _inside_?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: Probably with anchor `^` as well.

Comment: In the question topic, it is written get starting number  ? Can you please site an example where string is not starting with number and what would be expected output in that case ?

Comment: @PrashantKumar please check the update

Comment: We still do not know if a number can be inside a string, even if a string does not start with a number.

Comment: All the strings are still starting with number. In all the above examples `split` would be a good solution. I see you have added `2` in the 2nd example and dont want that in expected output. But that would be taken care by split.

Comment: @PrashantKumar What about the last example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a regex-based solution, we can try using `re.findall`:

```
inp = "5.0.0.1 This is not bad."
matches = re.findall(r'^\d+(?:\.\d+)*', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['5.0.0.1']
```

Comment: this works perfect

Comment: Please explain what is `?:` used for and what is `(...)` used for.

Comment: @stovfl Too long for a comment, have a look at a regex demo to better understand yourself: https://regex101.com/r/fwlJhZ/1

Comment: Thanks, I'm stuck with the term: ***non-capturing***. It simple throw away the matched Group 1  but doesen't be needed to make `findall` working.

Comment: No, the non capturing group _is_ needed, because without it, `re.findall` would only return the last captured quantity, which in general would be `.1` or dot followed by the last number in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first lead was good, as long as there is no space in your numbers:

```py
>>> '5.0.0.1 This is not bad.'.split(' ')[0]
> '5.0.0.1'
```